# Hide the Open / Edit Action in Search Hover Pane

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I know how to hide actions like Follow, View Library in the Hover Pane as they can be called by name e.g

```
    ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowFollowLink = false;
    ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowViewLibrary = false;
    ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowLastModifiedTime = false;
    ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowAuthors = false;
```

My question: Is it possible to hide the Open/Edit action? (I'd rather not hide the entire actions bar as I'd like to retain Send)

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Comment the below text in Item_CommonHoverPanel_Actions.html' file.

```
<div class="ms-srch-hover-action">        
    _#= editHmtl =#_               
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer. I should have said in my original question that I'd rather not edit the common actions. Rather I'd like to control it from the hover pane file like the other actions. .